# Multi-variable short redeclaration when inside a for loop creates a new variable?

Tags: go

The [documenation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) states:

> As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a multi-variable short declaration. **Redeclaration does not introduce a new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original**.

But how does this work in for loops? [See this example](https://play.golang.org/p/5HTYSMqKBe). It seems that the variable "nextPos", which has a scope outside the loop, actually gets redeclared inside the loop for the inner scope, and thus looses its value for each iteration. [This](https://play.golang.org/p/-GVefUDvuc) version works though.

Comment: Go has block-scope (unlike, say, Javascript). When you declare a variable, it's declared inside its' surrounding block. As you can have nested blocks, you can declare a variable under the same name in an inner block as in an outer. This is called shadowing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's show how it works, with these code samples:

Let's simplify your first sample, see this working sample code (1):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := 100
    {
        fmt.Println(a) // 100
        a, b := 0, 0
        fmt.Println(a, b) // 0 0
    }
    fmt.Println(a) // 100
}
```

output:

```
100
0 0
100
```

so `a` in `a, b := 0, 0` is **shadowed**, this `a` is new variable,
this is called Variable scoping and shadowing,
and you may name it e.g. `c` like this code for now to show how it works (2):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := 100
    {
        fmt.Println(a) // 100
        c, b := 0, 0
        fmt.Println(c, b) // 0 0
    }
    fmt.Println(a) // 100
}
```

the output is that same as (1):

```
100
0 0
100
```

and lets simplify your next sample code (3):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := 0
    b := byte(0)
    {
        fmt.Println(a, b) // 0 0
        a, b = 1, byte(1)
        fmt.Println(a, b) // 1 1
    }
    fmt.Println(a, b) // 1 1
}
```

output:

```
0 0
1 1
1 1
```

so here `a` and `b` are the same inside and outside loop.

also see: [Where can we use Variable Scoping and Shadowing in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553134/where-can-we-use-variable-shadowing-and-why)
and see:
[What is the difference between := and = in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512919/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-go/36513131#36513131)

Answer (score 1):

That's how the short assignment statement `:=` works. From the specs:

> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may
>   redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in
>   the same block (or the parameter lists if the block is the function
>   body) with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank variables
>   is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a
>   multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a
>   new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

Thus, in your first example, you can see that there is one new variable, namely `nextB`, and this re-declares `nextPos` as well for each loop iteration.

In the second case, both `nextB` and `nextPos` have already been declared and hence no re-declaration occurs. Also note that you are using `=` as the compiler would not allow `:=` for the same reason, i.e. no new variables declared.