# Why I can redefine the same variable multiple times in a for loop but can't outside of a loop?

Tags: variables, go

I have the following program.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        x := 77
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}
```

When executed I got:

```
77
77
```

As we can see, the `x := 77` has been execute 2 times. However, If I modify it slightly like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := 77
    fmt.Println(a)
    a := 77
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

I will get the error "no new variables on left side of `:=`". Why this?

Comment: In the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope

Comment: This really isn't specific to Golang.  It will behave similar for any language.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are a couple of things here. First let's address the second half of your question.

The default way to declare a variable is using the `var` keyword and then assign to it with the `=` operator.

```
var a int
a = 77
```

Go allows us a shortcut `:=` that both declares a variable and assigns a value

```
a := 77
```

In your example when you use `:=` a second time you're trying to redeclare a new variable named `a` in the same scope which is not allowed. The error `no new variables on left side of :=` is trying to tell you this.

But now to your original question, why can you do this multiple times inside a for loop?

The reason is each time you enter a block of curly braces `{}` you're creating a new nested scope. When you declare the variable `x` at the top of the loop it is a new variable and it goes out of scope at the end of the loop. When the program comes back around to the top of the loop again it's another new scope.

For example look at this code

```
{
    x := 77
    fmt.Println(x)
}
fmt.Println(x) // Compile error
```

That second `Println` fails because `x` does not exist in that scope.

Answer (score 3):

No identifier may be declared twice in the same
 block, and no identifier may be declared in both the file and package
 block.

And see: [What is the difference between := and = in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36512919/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-go)

---

You have new variable on each run of `for` here,
This code shows it by printing the address of `x`
([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HEIERlR4bR)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        x := 77
        fmt.Println(&x)
    }
}
```

output:

```
0x1040e0f8
0x1040e0fc
```

---

And if you need new variable in your second example you may shadow it
([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AtStQl-UC2)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := 77
    fmt.Println(&a)
    {
        a := 77
        fmt.Println(&a)
    }
}
```

output:

```
0x1040e0f8
0x1040e0fc
```

---

Also See: [Where can we use Variable Scoping and Shadowing in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36553134/in-golang-where-can-we-use-variable-scoping-and-shadowing-and-how)

Comment: I'm surprised the latter is allowed (e.g. set `a := 78` inside the inner scope, then check `a` before the function returns. I just spent hours tracking down a bug that was due to a variable being re-set in an inner-scope and being used later in an outer-scope without the modifications. Go's compiler is strict about other things, why not this? (It was hard to see because `:=` is not as immediately obvious as using the `var` keyword).